# Convertir Number a string

Tags: javascript, string, setinterval

Tengo un programa donde intento sumar cada 300 ms 0.01 a i y después fijar los decimales a dos, el problema es que después de realizar la suma, no puedo usar el `Number.toFixed()` porque me da un error de tipo. ¿Por qué ocurre esto?

```
let i = 0;
const int = setIntervalL(fun, 300);
function fun(){
   i = i + 0.01; 
   i = i.toFixed(2);//Error Uncaught TypeError: i.toFixed is not a function
}
```

¿Por qué ocurre esto?

Comment: **¿Porqué ocurre esto?** Simplemente porque [`toFixed `](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) devuelve *Una cadena que representa el número dado, usando notación de punto fijo.*

Comment: Dicho esto, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so] y te invito a realizar el [tour]. Usualmente no me gusta decir: *lee la documentación*, pero en este caso es muy evidente que antes de hacer la pregunta, tal vez, leyendo la documentación hubieras aclarado la duda. Toma esto en cuenta para futuras preguntas. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Exacto, si lanzas esto en un playground veras que no da error, pero el valor devuelto es un string

```js
let numero:decimal = 0.00;
setInterval(suma, 10);
function suma() {
  numero = numero + 0.01; 
  console.log(numero.toFixed(2))
}
```

Depende de para que lo quieras utilizar, puede valerte. Pero si nos das mas datos, te ayudaremos.